# How to marshal *big.Int with protocol buffers?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I want to create a protocol buffer message with `*big.Int` in Go. What's the best way?

Comment: Use `string`, or use `bytes` in protobuf, and  `Int.Bytes`/`Int.SetBytes`

Answer (score 2):

`big.Int` implements `encoding.TextMarshaler`: https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.MarshalText

... and you can easily serialize a `[]byte` into protobuf.

Comment: Do you propose to make a wrapper for a structure and use `message BigInt {bytes bigint = 1;}` and generate go file for a proto file with that simple message?

Comment: @RobertZaremba: well yes, `[]byte` is encoded as the protobuf `bytes` type. Not sure what structure and wrapper you're referring to.